# Java EE 6 Java Messaging Service Untracable NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, service, jms, messaging

I am trying to set up JMS within my GlassFish Project.

I am following the guidelines from the book: "Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3 Application Server".

I set up the Connector Resource to "jms/GlassFishWebDevConnectionFactory" and a queue to "jms/GlassFishWebDevQueue".

The following code is executed out of a Singleton Bean:

```
public class MessageSender {
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishWebDevConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishWebDevQueue")
    private Queue queue;
    public void postMessages() {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        }catch (JMSException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MessageSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The initialization of the application fails at "Connection con = connectionFactory.createConnection();" with a NullPointerException.

This is the complete stacktrace:

```
javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton WorldBean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:547)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tier_controller.MessageSender.postMessages(MessageSender.java:31)
    at tier_controller.WorldBean.init(WorldBean.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:538)
    ... 40 more<code>
```

I meddled with this for many hours now and I checked every tipp I found twice. The required resources are running and the @Resource Syntax should be valid, too.

I am at a complete loss regarding how I should trace or fix this error.

Comment: Your connectionFactory is null, it's not getting initialized by your container. I'd start from there...

Comment: Well, yes of course it is null... The question is why. The namespace is right, the ressource is connected and I followed every single step in the book. I came across a LOT of similiar questions while researching, but not a single response which explained why it could be null..

Comment: Your code is correct. Explain how you setup the JMS and ConnectionFactory in GlassFish admin console

Answer (score 0):

It you want to debug it to find out what's the problem - you can set up suspend flag in the jpda options, so that you'll be able to connect to debug *before* app started to initialise.
Plus, you can set up breakpoint exceptions for the NPE in your IDE (Run->View breakpoints->.. in the Intellij Idea) if it is needed.

Comment: I solved it eventually. The problem was, that the servlet did not have the loadOnStartup=1 annotation. I am still not convinced, why this is actually a problem, but it fixed the issue.